# Method that returns an array in Java can be private?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static

I read a Java text book and I have a question.

**Syntax**

```
public static Base_Type[] Method_Name(Parameter_List)
{
   Base_Type[] temp = new Base_Type[Array_Size];
   *Statements_To_Fill_Array*
   return temp;
}
```

The book says *"The method need not be static and need not be public."*

Why? Can you explain why the method need not be static or public?

And I would like to know the advantage or disadvantage of making returning array method be public static method.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without more context. The quoted statement on its own is bullshit. It all depends on the structure of your classes and what you need to do.

Comment: I understand what you said. maybe I should have written more information about my question but I think through below answer, I solved my curiosity. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. well you can make it private only if you are using the method in the class where is declared. if you call it from an other object, then you have to make it public/protected.
2. you should make a method static when the method doesn't use its own class variables. if a class has public and static methods, then that's a code smell for me. I would extract static methods in classes which contains only static methods

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this method is supposed to be used only inside your class.

1) We make methods public only when they are supposed to be called outside the class declaration.

2) We make methods static when we want to call the method without creating an object of the class.

Of course, you could make any methods public or static if you want, but that would violate the main OOP principles.